# Can I use a floating wood floor in a half bath?

Tags: bathroom, hardwood-floor

Will a floating wood floor work well in a half bath?  If so I have another question.  Should the toilet flange go over the floor or should the floor be cut around it?  Thanks.

Comment: I would expect the humidity and unavoidable splashes to wreak havoc on an engineered wood floor in a bathroom.

Answer (score 3):

If your bathroom is used mostly by responsible adults, there's no reason for concern. Plenty of kitchens (including my own) have wood floors. The rare splash should be wiped up, and a strategically placed rug can provide more protection.

Floating floors usually go around the flange.